# fseek() crossing file limit and not terminating

Tags: c, fseek

In the last while loop, every 5th character stored in the file should be printed, but the loop is going on indefinitely and not terminating.
the feof() function should return 1 on reaching END OF FILE and the loop should be exited but the loop is going on indefinitely.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
  long n, k;
  char c;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("RANDOM", "w");

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    putc(c, fp);
  }

  n = ftell(fp);
  printf("\nNo. of characters entered by the user is : %ld\n", n);
  fclose(fp);
  fp = fopen("RANDOM", "r");

  while(feof(fp) == 0) {
    n = ftell(fp);
    c = getc(fp);
    printf("The character at %ld position is %c\n", n, c);
    fseek(fp, 4l, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: 1.) see [why while( !feof() ) is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: 2.) you don't reassign `fp` with your second `fopen( "RANDON", "r" )`

Comment: You are using `feof()` and `ftell()` then you are even reading from a closed file. You probably wanted to `fp = fopen("RANDOM", "r");`.

Comment: Exactly. This invokes *undefined behavior*. You closed the `fp`, opened the file again and leaked the resulting result (likely a valid `FILE*`) never to be seen again, then sent the old, still closed, `fp` in to your loop. Short version: you're missing `fp = ` in this code.

Comment: actually that was a copy mistake, it is still not working with the `fp =`  added.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish using `c = getchar()) != EOF` ?

Comment: it will take input from the user until the user presses `ctrl-d` which assign EOF meaning end of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man fseek()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek):

> A successful call to the `fseek()` function clears the end-of-file indicator for the stream.

And `fseek()` will be successful even when you set the position indicator behind EOF.
So it becomes clear that `while (feof(fp) == 0)` will never terminate when `fseek()` is the last command within the loop.

Instead, you could do:

```
for( ;; ) {
    n = ftell(fp);
    if( (c = getc(fp)) == EOF )
         break;
    printf("The character at %ld position is %c\n", n, c);
    fseek(fp, 4l, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Comment: Please don't repeat the error of using the magic number `1` as the third argument to `fseek()`.  The only proper values are `SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR`, and `SEEK_END`.